# How to arrange rows based on other column in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data in my google sheet (Sheet1)

| A | B (Price) | C ..... F (other columns) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Grape | 0.80 |  |
| Pineapple | 0.90 |  |
| Orange | 1.20 |  |
| Blueberry | 2.10 |  |
| Kiwi | 3.00 |  |
| Durian | 1.50 |  |
| Mango | 4.00 |  |

...
...
...

I have another table in Sheet2 that have same fruits but in random sequence.

How do i arrange the rows in Sheet2 to be exactly the same sequence of the fruits in Sheet1? I have tried the Query function but still unable to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method I found is using MATCH formula:

[image]

=match(H2,$B$2:$B,0)

This adds a column that contains order of fruits in first table. Then you can use Menu --> Data --> Sort Range and sort your range by this column in a way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below query:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:B7, "SELECT A,B")
```

This will select both columns of data from `Sheet1`.

#### Reference

- [QUERY Formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en);
- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).